# Is there any way to simplify this code

Tags: scala

I'd like to simplify  this Scala code:

```
private def getToken() = {
    val token = getTokenFromDb()
    token match {
      case Some(x) => token
      case None => {
        val remoteToken = getTokenRemote()
        remoteToken match {
          case Some(x) => {
            writeTokenToDb(x)
            remoteToken
          }
          case None => None
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private def getToken(): Option[Token] = {
  def remoteToken =
    getTokenRemote() map { r => writeTokenToDb(r); r }
  getTokenFromDb orElse remoteToken
}
```

Please write always the type of a function for outer functions - it makes it far more readable to understand the source code (often it is useful to add the types to inner functions/declarations as well).

Beside from that you can also write `case t: Some => t` or `case t @ Some(_) => t` to express that you return the matched type. Your way of `case Some(x) => token` is hard to understand, because one needs to know what's `token`.

Furthermore, you don't need braces around a match block, you can simply write

```
case x =>
  a
  b
```

And naming a variable in a similar way as a function, like in `val token = getToken()` is completely unnecessary, when it is only used once, it also doesn't increase readability. In such cases just inline the function call: `getToken match { ... }`.

Comment: it seems like you make an unnecessary recursive call  in `def getToken()`. How can it return `Some(x)` in ` `getToken orElse remoteToken` ? It will call itself recursively.

Comment: it's my miss, it should be `getTokenFromDb`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Alex: You are right, that was a mistake.